# How can you bulk update contacts found using search kit?

Tags: contacts, profile, searchkit

Is anyone else having issues updating contacts via profile using searchkit? I click the contacts I want to update, I select update profile using actions - I choose the profile - then nothing happens. 5.69.5

Replicated in demo master - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsearch#/edit/43

When I go to bulk profile update any of them - I cant.

For now - I add contacts to a group then go to group via manage groups and update the contacts there.

Answer (score 3):

There are [known bugs](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3869) with the "Profile Update" action, however fixing them has been low-priority because there is another alternative: in SearchKit you can select the "Update Contacts" action which allows you to choose values directly, without needing to configure a profile.

[image: SearchKit Update]

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a solution as that overwrites values and that is not intended. We want to add and remove values depending on other criteria. Thanks for the update though, glad to know I am not alone.